# Can I export custom data from a Contact, an Organization and an Activity in one export?

Tags: export, activity, field-mapping

I am trying to set up a custom field mapping to export after I search for Activities.  I would like to export data associated with the Activity, but also include data from the Individual Contact and related Organization.  All the fields are available when I export my activity, but the data does not export for the Organization.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Christine - do you mean there is a 'related org' field that is available when setting up the export mapping but which doesn't actually export the data?

Comment: Yes.   I can add them to the export data mapping, but no data exports.  I have relationships with employees of an organization and wanted to export custom data fields associated with the Org along with data from a completed activity and the Individual.   Thanks

Comment: If you have access to your db and have some mysql skills then you can possibly do the required in one view. Similarly if your CMS is Drupal then you can probably build (or have built for you) a View display with an export that contains all the required info in one query

Answer (score 1):

There is a very useful extension called "[**Extended Reports**](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports)" that has an Activities report that allows you to pull information about the Source, Target and Assigned contacts, but if you are looking for information about an organization that is related to one of those contacts but is not directly linked to the activity (and you don't have access to a developer), then you'd probably be better off searching twice:

1. Search > Advanced Search
2. **Search 1:**

   > 1. Select "Display Results as" = Activities
   > 2. Enter desired search criteria for Activities
   > 3. Search and Export search results
3. **Search 2:**

   > 1. Without changing the criteria you used to search for the activities, click to expand the Edit Search Criteria bar
   > 2. Select "Display Results as" = Related Contacts
   > 3. Select the relevant relationship
   > 4. Export results
4. Use a [**vlookup**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function to match data accordingly (facilitated if you export contact IDs)

Hope this helps!
Tamar

Comment: Thanks Tamar.   I was trying to avoid 2 searches, but it looks like I may not be able to.   I appreciate your answer.